# Is it possible to setup Event Bubbling and Event Tunelling for standard class not just for XAML classes?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, xaml

In a WPF or Silverlight Is it possible to have a custom hierarchy of standard classes not associated with GUI classes and setup vent Bubbling and Event Tunelling for this hierarchy ? How ?

when looking at events I don't see anything really related to bubbling or tunneling
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement_events.aspx

Comment: Follow the link you provided.  Follow the first link: DragEnter. Look in the section "Routing Strategy" and will find the word "Bubbling".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible using the .net framework,  unless you create something similar to the functionality the EventManager class provides you. 
Suppose you started implementing. Then you would have to traverse up & down a graph of objects (if your class hierarchy isn't a tree). For this you would somehow need to identify which objects are actually are part of the tree and which aren't.
Suppose you have the following:

```
class A
{
   public B b;
}

class B
{

}


B b1 = new B();
A a1 = new A() { b = b1 };
A a2 = new A() { b = b1 };
```

Suppose b1 raises a bubbling event. To which parent should it bubble? a1 or a2?
Bubbling & tunneling in WPF & Silverlight work because you have UIElements which are in a Tree, not in a graph like in the scenario above. But arbitrary class hierachies are graphs not trees.
So if you would start implementing something similar it would only work for a tree class similar to the following.

```
class Node 
{
   Node parent;
   //other members
}
```

Then you would know how to always bubble using the "parent" property.

But, before you start implementing your EventManager, I would suggest you take another look at what RoutedEvents are and what are the scenarios to use them: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx
Also maybe you could provide us with the scenarios where routed events would be useful for a standard (non-ui) class hierachy (tree) to see if we can find an alternative to RoutedEvents.

Comment: Hi thanks. Well there's no reason you wouldn''t a hierarchy of non-visual classes and so routed events can be usefull also.

Answer (score 2):

Routed events require that the object inherits from [UIElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.aspx) class, which pretty much destines it to be a GUI control.

All such classes *can* be instantiated from code behind (C#/VB/...) though. XAML just provides a convenient way to declaratively define objects, it doesn't do anything that can't be done from code behind.

Comment: Thanks when looking at events I don't see anything really related to bubbling or tunneling though http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement_events.aspx

Comment: @user310291 The key is [AddHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598898.aspx) method and the fact that UIElement knows is place in the element hierarchy (inherited from [Visual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.aspx)).